# What is the difference in meaning and usage between "excoriate" and "execrate"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

Both nearly mean *to criticise*. So, what is the difference in usage?

Comment: Sounds like you may have been reading some Thomas Covenant? :)

Comment: I disagree. They don't both mean to criticise. A simple synonym of 'execrate' is to hate something.

Answer (score 3):

*Execrate* was more widely used a century ago that *excoriate*, now it's the other order (though both are little used). Google ngram results (which are confirmed by the Corpus of Contemporary American English):

[image]

<sup>(blue: excoriate; red: execrate; green: excoriaged; yellow: execrated)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The underlying meaning of excoriate is *to flay the skin off*, and execrate means *to curse*.

Both words are used somewhat figuratively in the sense of *criticise very harshly*, and both are quite uncommon - so much so that probably this figurative sense probably accounts for most occurrences of each.

The words look and sound similar, are both used with exactly the same figurative sense, and are both relatively unfamiliar to even fluent speakers. If you intended to use *one*, but forgot the exact word, it's pretty much a 50% chance you'd end up coming across the *other* word first by looking things up.

Which wouldn't matter - everyone else is doing the same thing, so in the end we may as well say the two words are exact equivalents in this sense. People here may laboriously set out supposed differences here, but they won't have normally been significant to a speaker actually choosing which of the two words to use.

Comment: I think you would see *excoriate* with some frequency in print.  I'm thinking of writing with a slightly elevated tone, either from literature or in opinion or review pieces from somewhere like the *new york times*, *harper's* etc.,

Comment: @jgbelacqua: I wouldn't disagree. I think *excoriate* wouldn't be out of place in such august publications today. *Execrate* though seems more quaint - still usable, but to me at least it has medieval & priestly overtones that maybe wouldn't have been intended by the writer.

Comment: I think most of what you say is unwarranted. Can you give even the slightest evidence that, 'everyone else is doing the same thing'?  With the greatest respect, the fact that you find it difficult to distinguish these words has no relevance to the knowledge of others. My guess is that most people have never heard of either word. A goodly percentage don't know the difference but that those who know the true meaning of one probably also know the meaning of the other.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention my downvote. I believe in telling people when I down vote them.

Comment: @chasly from UK: I never said ***I*** had trouble distinguishing the literal meanings of the words. I can assure you I don't - if I'd had any uncertainties I'd have presumably Googled them 4 years ago when writing this answer, and would naturally have included links to the two definitions in the first sentence of my answer. But arguably it would be somewhat unseemly for me to amass evidence proving that I have a wider vocabulary than most.

Comment: ...btw - I disagree with your assertion that *a simple synonym of 'execrate' is to hate something*. Let's face it, no-one ever says *I execrate him!* It's just that adjectival *execrated* and *execrable* (literally, "accursed" are often used somewhat figuratively to mean *detested, hated*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - No-one ever says it? Here's just one example of many: *To this Landor might have replied, as he had written some months before to Southey, that he hated Buonaparte, "I execrate him: but I detest our own government worse"* https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ycENAAAAIAAJ&q=%22i+execrate+him%22&dq=%22i+execrate+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAWoVChMI1t-ojdSNyAIVNAbbCh2pLQ6M

Answer (score 3):

- excoriate - you're yelling directly at someone
- execrate - you're yelling about them (but not necessarily to their face)

Comment: Could you say where you got these definitions? They don't seem to agree with any dictionaries I can find - especially the one for 'excoriate'.

Comment: Good observation. They actually aren't definitions and I hope would not be used that way. Presumably the OP has already seen all the dictionary definitions and still can't tell the difference. I am explaining pragmatically in what situation one would use those words.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I can find is that *excoriate* is reported by the NOAD as formal word, while *execrate* is not reported to be formal.

As per the meaning, *execrate* means "feel or express great loathing for;" the fact I feel an intense dislike doesn't mean I am criticizing somebody.

Comment: I have upvoted this but you seem to contradict yourself. First you say the only difference is the level of formality but then you point out that the words have completely different meanings.